# Data type for SQL aggregate functions (COUNT, SUM, AVG)

Tags: sql, odbc, oledb

New to SQL. Say I run this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(SupplierID) AS "TotalSuppliers"
FROM Products;
```

This will return a single row with a field called "TotalSuppliers". In my database, the result was "778".

When tested in C# using `typeof`, the type for this field was `short` (the ODBC `SMALLINT` or OleDB `SmallInt` data type). This matched the data type of the `SupplierID` column.

Do I have control over the type used for the alias/temporary column? For example, is it possible to run `COUNT` or `SUM` on a column that is ODBC `SMALLINT` and use the `INTEGER` or `DOUBLE` data type in the output?

Comment: The SupplierID data type has no importance for the count() result data type. It's a number of rows that is returned, no matter if the column is numeric, timestamp, character etc.

Comment: However, SUM and AVG will have a data type based on the input column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert in the query:

```
select cast(count(*) as double) as TotalSuppliers
```

However, this is the type *in the database*.  ODBC is still responsible for the conversion to your application type.

Note:  In most databases, `count(*)` should be returning an int -- usually 4 bytes.  I wonder if on your system `smallint` is really 4 bytes.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, as quick as ever. What is the precise syntax? I've tried `SELECT CAST(COUNT(SupplierID) AS DOUBLE) AS "TotalSuppliers") FROM Products;` and this returns no data.

Comment: @AlainD . . . The code in your comment has a superfluous `)`.

Comment: Ah good spot...but still no data when I corrected that. Had no idea this might be relevant, but I'm using MS Access and the Jet engine. From a brief internet search `CAST` appears to be specific to SQL Server.

Comment: @AlainD . . . No.  `CAST()` is standard SQL.  You need to use the appropriate bespoke function for MS Access.  It really is just barely SQL, in my opinion, missing so much of common standard SQL functionality.

Comment: Found them! Its `CInt` for "Int16", `CLng` for "Int32" and `CDbl` for "double" (and a few others). Full syntax would be `SELECT CDbl(COUNT(SupplierID)) AS "TotalSuppliers" FROM Products;`. Thanks Gordon! Must admit, this is pretty ugly, and motivates me to upgrade the database when possible to something more SQL-compliant. Shall I edit the answer to include that detail about `CInt` and `CDbl`?

Comment: use Count(1) for more speed

Answer (score 0):

If you're just running a query you can cast the result like Gordon suggested.

If you need the column in a stored table you can create a table and insert the value of the COUNT or SUM to a column in the table that is either ODBC SMALLINT and use the INTEGER or DOUBLE data type.

Using the alias/temporary values you assign it to.